# What is the Minimum Number of Candidates?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

What is the minimum number of candidates needed for an election of moderators to proceed to the final, election, phase? What happens if there are not enough?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the type of election. For this one, a regular one, if there are not enough candidates to have a competitive election (three, because there are two seats), the nomination period is extended by one week. If after that week, there are still not enough candidates, the election is cancelled.

(The rules are different for pro-tempore elections and graduation elections on beta sites; in those cases, the candidates may simply be appointed in the end.)

For more information, have a look at [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: We now have enough candidates (3)!

Comment: @Laurel Great! Now I'm wondering why you made this edit - I don't think there's *any* difference in the rendered post?

Comment: Hmmmm, it wasn't rendering for me. I was seeing the bare URL and I'm not sure why because you're right, it should expand. (It's working now for whatever reason.)

Comment: The URL didn't expand for me the first time I looked at it as well.

Comment: Wasn't rendering for me until after the edit either (can confirm the auto-title works now).

Comment: That's super weird (perhaps worth a bug report on Meta.SE), since it's something done by the server when submitting the post, not when retrieving it to be read ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Are you sure about that? It doesn't replace the URL in the stored text with the title and a link. It expands it on the fly; that's why it changes when the title of the post you're linking to changes. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I [asked about it on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380987/323179), but the bare links I included there were all successfully transformed into titles.

Comment: @ColleenV it doesn't change the Markdown (source code of the post) but each revision is stored as HTML, and the Markdown-to-HTML converter takes care of the expansion. See the bottom of https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5761/revisions - that shows as a formatted link to me. That's how I *thought* the initial post looked like, and definitely how it should - especially given the latest edit was a rollback to the first revision.

Comment: @Glorfindel But surely it doesn't just render that HTML once and never render it again? The titles in expanded links do get updated, I'm almost positive.

Comment: @ColleenV only after edits - this recently came up on Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380923/295232. FWIW the revision list I linked to is different; that is generated on the fly based on the Markdown of all revisions.

Comment: So Laurel's edits forced a re-render and "fixed" it. There were some intermittent server issues the other day, maybe the expansion timed out. Where you using the wysiwyg editor or the raw markup?

Comment: @ColleenV I guess so ... there's only the raw editor on all sites but Meta.SE and Meta.SO (and SO Teams) so I can't blame the editor.

Comment: Ah so I see. I could have sworn I could turn the other editor on from my profile at one point.